# Coded UI : UIControl not visible exception is throwing when trying to click next(page navigation button) in IE11

Tags: visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

We have a Coded  UI hybrid framework and what ever the actions that I have to perform there is a generic code which basically does that. Like Mouse click events.

So here is my problem. Control is visible but through coded ui it is throwing control is not visible error.

It is working fine in IE8,IE9 and IE10 the issue seems to exists only in IE11

```
Mouse.Click(Uicontrol);
```

However when the script was running if I scroll and make sure that the control is visible. Mouse Click event was successful.

I have tried various options like `EnsureClickable` but with no luck.

Please let me know how i can resolve this issue. That would be great help.

Also please let me know if you need any more information to understand the problem. Thanks

Update : The below is the generic code.

```
case Constants.Action:
  try
  {
    //Saving execution time by checking if testdata value was blank or NOT.
    if (pair.Value == "")
    {
      break;
    }
    MasterControls control = testMasterControlsDataOrdered.FirstOrDefault(cn => cn.ControlLogicalName == pair.Key); //Iteration fix
```

And below somewhere

```
if (pair.Value.ToString().ToUpper() == "CLICK")
{
  Mouse.Click(uiControl);
  uiLogFile.WriteToLogFile(CommomUtilities.MessageType.Info, "Action Click on " + control.ControlType + ", " + control.ControlLogicalName + " is done.");
}
```

The test data consists of Action --- Click and that is how I basically do action events.

Comment: Try to use the DrawHighlight() on that control just to see if it's finding the control that you are expecting to see.

Comment: The issue is with the coded ui. The coded Ui when identifying the controls. It is searching against the friendly name property which has some unwanted white spaces. 

The issue can be resolved by removing Friendly name from the Property search details. 
Or Trim the Friendly name Properties.